# Does the product fit into the carton?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with products p (size in millimeters):

```
| product_id | length | width | height
| -----------|----------------|-------
| 100        | 500    | 600   | 700
| 101        | 800    | 400   | 500
```

and a dataframe with cartons c (size in millimeters):

```
| carton_id  | length | width | height
| -----------| --------------|-------|-------
| 66        | 650    | 650   | 750
| 67        | 630    | 620   | 705
| 68        | 750    | 550   | 550
```

I have ~1000 products and ~50 different cartons for now.

For each product I need to know into which cartons it fits.

So I have to rotate the carton and/or product to see if it fits in every Lenght*Width*Height combination.

I found the "knapsack problem" but that is for multiple products into one box, not one product into one box?

How can I do this with pandas?

Result should look like:

```
| product_id | carton_id
| -----------| ---------
| 100        | 66
| 100        | 67
```

Comment: Please paste data as plain text rather than with any special formatting. Just paste output of `print(dataframe)`

Comment: Do you also care about reorientation? E.g. if you can rotate a product by 90 degrees, then the length becomes the width, and it may fit into cartons that it did not fit into before.

Comment: You can rotate the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import itertools

values = carton.values[:, 1:]

combi = [np.column_stack([x,y,z]) 
        for x, y, z in itertools.permutations([values[:,0],values[:,1],values[:,2]])]
new_values = np.concatenate(combi)
new_index = carton.carton_id.tolist() * len(combi)
new = np.column_stack([new_index, new_values])
new_carton = pd.DataFrame(new, columns=['carton_id', 'length', 'width', 'height'])


df = pd.merge(product, new_carton, how='cross', suffixes=('_prod', '_cart'))
df = df[(df.length_cart>df.length_prod) 
   & (df.width_cart>df.width_prod)
   & (df.height_cart>df.height_prod)]
df = df[['product_id', 'carton_id']].drop_duplicates()

print(df)

   product_id  carton_id
0         100         66
1         100         67
```

Comment: It is not as easy as it seems. @tomtomfox Where have you considered all possible combinations?

Comment: @tomtomfox in current version 1.2.0+ of pandas, `merge` has [how='cross'](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) parameter where you don't need to create the pseudo join 'key' in each dataframe any more.

Comment: @ScottBoston, thanks for the information, it will be very useful

Comment: @Vishnudev all combination are considered with the cartesian product formed with the cross join, then you filter this result to only those combinations that meet your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
# take the `id` columns to indexes
p = p.set_index("product_id")
c = c.set_index("carton_id")

# get products row-wise
pp = p.prod(axis=1).to_numpy()
cc = c.prod(axis=1).to_numpy()

# compare each row of `pp` against each row of `cc`
cross_compare = np.less.outer(pp, cc)

# matmul via making use of booleans are integers
# to select the appropriate carton_id's
result = cross_compare.dot(c.index + " ")

# put the result into a dataframe
out = pd.DataFrame({"product_id": p.index, "carton_id": result})
```

to get

```
>>> out

   product_id  carton_id
0         100  66 67 68
1         101  66 67 68
```